# Cant not get updated values in pdf?

Tags: c#, itext, dynamics-crm

I'm using c# to write pdf file.
with the following code

```
MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream();
Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
doc.SetMargins(40f, 40f, 40f, 20f);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem);
byte[] generated_pdf_file = mem.GetBuffer();
mem.Close();

return generated_pdf_file;
```

all things worked for except when any data changed, the pdf print the original one. It means cant not get new instance of the new entered data.

any help?

Answer (score 1):

`getBuffer()` is not the right way of going about this.
Convert to an array first by calling `toArray()`.

Also, a few other remarks about your code.

- You set the margins of the document in the constructor, and you immediately change them.
- You get the memory bytes before you flush the document to memory by closing it.
- You tagged Dynamics CRM, but nothing in your code is about Dynamics CRM.

Comment: While certainly 100% true, this does not really answer the OP's question. Thus, this more is material for comments.

Comment: before memory byte there is block of code I did not mention i. it include, opening, writing  and then closing document. I tagged CRM because make a button in CRM which is linked to this project. thanks for helping but still when I change Getbuffer to toArray. the problem is the same.